# Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead - AndroidStudio

Tags: android

I am having an error compiling the application.

Android Studio

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 12
        versionName "2.0.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.bottomnavigation:bottom-navigation:2.0.1-rc1' //1.0.7
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    compile 'com.dmitrymalkovich.android:material-design-dimens:1.4'

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and gradle version is 4.1

Answer (score 1):

The third party android-apt plugin is no longer supported. You should switch to the built-in annotation processor support, which has been improved to handle resolving dependencies lazily.

When using the Android plugin 3.0.0, you must add annotation processors to the processor classpath using the annotationProcessor dependency configuration, as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version-number>'
}
```